# Generating two objects in OpenGl with c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl

I would like to draw two objects to the screen.

In [this very simple tutorial by Etay Meiri](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial02/tutorial02.tar.gz) he creates a dot on the screen.  I tried expanding it to two dots (wow), but I simply can't understand how to draw the second object.

This is what I tried:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#include "math_3d.h"

GLuint VBO;

static void RenderSceneCB()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, 1);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glutSwapBuffers();
}


static void InitializeGlutCallbacks()
{
    glutDisplayFunc(RenderSceneCB);
}

static void CreateVertexBuffer() {

    Vector3f Object[1];
    Object[0] = Vector3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    // Added another object
    Vector3f Object2[1];
    Object2[0] = Vector3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    glGenBuffers(2, &VBO); // Incrementet the number of buffers to 2
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Object), Object, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Object2), Object, GL_STATIC_DRAW); // Added another buffer
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE|GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowSize(1024, 768);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow("Tutorial 02");

    InitializeGlutCallbacks();

    // Must be done after glut is initialized!
    GLenum res = glewInit();
    if (res != GLEW_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: '%s'\n", glewGetErrorString(res));
        return 1;
    }

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    CreateVertexBuffer();

    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

The mat file:

```
#ifndef MATH_3D_H
#define MATH_3D_H


struct Vector3f
{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;

    Vector3f()
    {
    }

    Vector3f(float _x, float _y, float _z)
    {
        x = _x;
        y = _y;
        z = _z;
    }
};

#endif  /* MATH_3D_H */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From OpenGl documentation:

`glGenBuffers` returns n buffer object names in buffers. There is no guarantee that the names form a contiguous set of integers; however, it is guaranteed that none of the returned names was in use immediately before the call to glGenBuffers.

So, you must provide an array for buffers allocation:

```
GLuint VBO[2];  // 2 objects
....
glGenBuffers(2, VBO);
```

Now, add information to buffers:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO[0]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Object), Object, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO[1]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Object2), Object2, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

(Note: be carefull to use both objects, not like actually that you are using the same object `Object`)

Comment: Thank you. How about the function renderSceneCB()? I tried adding: 
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO[1]);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO[2]);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
But it resulted in an exception :/ (sorry, newbie)

Comment: No, no, no. Remember, in C, as C++, arrays are zero based. So, correct ones are `VBO[0]` and `VBO[1]`. Other values will result in a exception.

Comment: Ah yes of course.. Thank you for your patience. The program runs now, but I only get the last defined object onto the screen. I call glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3); after each glVertexAtrribPointer()..